# Redux component is not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Need some help on React-Redux, I am not able to figure out, what I am missing on to make my modal work. Can you help me with this?. I see the state is changing but the component is not rendering and modal is not displaying.

Here is my code . You can find repo [here](https://github.com/CodeguruEdison/modal)

`Entity`

```
 export interface IModal {
        modalType: string;
        modalProps:IModalProps
    }

    export interface IModalProps {
        open:boolean;
    }

    export interface IModalManagerProps {
        currentModal?:IModal;
        closeModal?:()=>void;
    }

    export interface ILoginModalProps {
        closeModal:()=>void;
    }

    export interface IRegisterModalProps {
        closeModal:()=>void;
    }
   export interface IModalState {
     modal:IModal 
   }
```

`Actions`

```
import { ActionCreator } from 'redux';
import { IModalOpenAction, ModalActionTypes, IModalCloseAction } from './modalConstant';
import { IModal } from './Entity/modal';


export const openModalAction:ActionCreator<IModalOpenAction>=(modalpayload:IModal)=>{
    return {
         type:ModalActionTypes.MODAL_OPEN,
         payload:modalpayload 
    }
 }

 export const closeModalAction:ActionCreator<IModalCloseAction>=(modalpayload:IModal)=>{
     return {
         type:ModalActionTypes.MODAL_CLOSE,
         payload: modalpayload
     }
 }
```

`Reducer`

```
import { ModalAction, ModalActionTypes } from "./modalConstant";
import { IModalState } from "./Entity/IModalState";
import { IModal } from "./Entity/modal";
import { Reducer } from "redux";

const initialModal: IModal = {
  modalType: "",
  modalProps: {
    open: false
  }
};
const initialModalState: IModalState = {
  modal: initialModal
};

export const modalReducer: Reducer<IModalState, ModalAction> = (
  state = initialModalState,
  action: ModalAction
):IModalState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ModalActionTypes.MODAL_OPEN: {
      return {
        modal:{
          modalType: action.payload.modalType,
          modalProps: action.payload.modalProps
        }
      };
    }
    case ModalActionTypes.MODAL_CLOSE: {
      return initialModalState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default modalReducer;
```

`RootReducer`

```
import { ModalAction, ModalActionTypes } from "./modalConstant";
import { IModalState } from "./Entity/IModalState";
import { IModal } from "./Entity/modal";
import { Reducer } from "redux";

const initialModal: IModal = {
  modalType: "",
  modalProps: {
    open: false
  }
};
const initialModalState: IModalState = {
  modal: initialModal
};

export const modalReducer: Reducer<IModalState, ModalAction> = (
  state = initialModalState,
  action: ModalAction
):IModalState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ModalActionTypes.MODAL_OPEN: {
      return {
        modal:{
          modalType: action.payload.modalType,
          modalProps: action.payload.modalProps
        }
      };
    }
    case ModalActionTypes.MODAL_CLOSE: {
      return initialModalState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default modalReducer;
```

`config store`

```
import { IModalState } from './../../features/modals/Entity/IModalState';

import { createStore, Store  } from "redux"

import {composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';

export interface IApplicationState {

    form:any,
    modals:IModalState 

}
export  function configureStore(): Store<IApplicationState> {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer,composeWithDevTools());
    return store;
  }
```

`App`

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {openModalAction } from './features/modals/modalActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { IModal } from './features/modals/Entity/modal';
import { ModalManager } from './features/modals/modalManager';
export interface IAppProps {
  openModal:(modal:IModal)=>void,
}
const  App:FC<IAppProps>=(props)=> {
 const{openModal}=props;
  const handleOpenModal =()=>{
    openModal({
      modalType:'TestModal',
      modalProps:{
        open:true
      }
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ModalManager></ModalManager>
    <Button onClick={handleOpenModal}>
    Open modal
  </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {

  openModal:openModalAction
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

`Modal Manager`

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { IModalManagerProps } from "./Entity/modal";
import { IApplicationState } from "../../app/store/configureStore";
import LoginModal from "./LoginModal";
import RegisterModal from "./RegisterModal";
import TestModal from "./TestModal";

const modalLookUp: any = {
  TestModal: TestModal,
  LoginModal: LoginModal,
  RegisterModal: RegisterModal
};
//export const ModalManager= (props:any) => {
export const ModalManager: FC<IModalManagerProps> = props => {
  const { currentModal } = props;

  console.log(currentModal);
  let renderedModal = null;
  if (currentModal) {
    const { modalProps } = currentModal;
    const ModalComponent = modalLookUp['TestModal'];
    renderedModal = <ModalComponent {...modalProps} />;
  }

  return <span>{renderedModal}</span>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (store: IApplicationState) => {
  return {
    currentModal: store.modals.modal
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ModalManager);
```

`test modal`

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { closeModalAction } from "./modalActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


export const TestModal = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal closeIcon="close" open={true}>
        <Modal.Header>Test Modal</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Content>
          <Modal.Description>
            <p>Test Modal... nothing to see here</p>
          </Modal.Description>
        </Modal.Content>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  closeModal:closeModalAction
 };
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TestModal);
```

Comment: I pored over this code for a while and nothing immediately jumps out, but I suspect `ModalManager` is part of it. Use the react dev tools to inspect what it's prop values are and what it's returning to the DOM.

Comment: I see state values are changing but modal manager is not re rendering, I did exactly same in plane JavaScript it is working. You can check github repo from above.

Comment: I've isolated your `ModalManager` in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/keen-hopper-vgykx?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) and it seems to see the `currentModal` prop update. Are you sure your state is updating? Is it mapped to props correctly?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I see the state is updating, you can find repo https://github.com/CodeguruEdison/modal . I have checked your code, but the issue with redux connect.

Comment: The closest example is https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/ but I am doing typescript.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the issue.

I was importing like below

```
import { ModalManager } from './features/modals/modalManager';
```

but it should  be

```
import  ModalManager  from './features/modals/modalManager';
```

Comment: Awesome you got it figured out.